# "What were they doing differently *that* had led to this dramatic improvement?"

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, that, what-that

> What were they doing differently that had led to this dramatic improvement?

I saw a sentence having the same structure as the one above. But I am not sure that this sentence is grammatically correct. I would like to know your opinions.

---

The "that" in the sentence seems a relative pronoun, but where is the antecedent? When I speculate what it says, the antecedent could be the "what". Is it possible?

Comment: Might help if you point out the specific bit you feel is wonky.

Comment: At face value, this sentence looks fine.  It could definitely use some more context though.

Comment: You speculate correctly.  "That" refers to thing being asked about with "what.'

Comment: The _Wh_-clause -- more specifically, its answer -- is the antecedent of _that_ (or _which_), the subject of _had led_. The answer itself is indefinite, and amounts to a pro-verb _do `what`_. Clearly it's not a noun but an action. The _Wh_-clause itself is an NP, though, so it can take a relative clause.

Comment: The tenses are reversed.  s/b "What _had they been doing_ that _led_ to this dramatic improvement?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that_ is the antecedent of the relative clause, which is shifted by "heavy clause extraposition".

Comment: Thank you. So then, you could say "What that surprised you did they do?"

Comment: You could say it, but to me _What did they do that surprised you_ would be more natural.